# How to map SharePoint site folder as network drive using C#?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, network-drive

I have requirement to map SharePoint site folder as network drive. Kindly help me with this.

Comment: There are no site folders - there are lists and document libraries. Only document libraries can be used as networks shares. Can you see that library as a network share to begin with? If not, you can't map it in any other way

Comment: Hello, sorry, I meant mapping Document Library. I could map manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of a script which I use on a windows server.  I also unmap the drive with a net use delete script in front of it to avoid the prompt of overwriting the same drive letter.

NET USE X: "\projects.xxxx.com\MyProject\Shared Documents\My_Folder" /user:USER123 password123 /persistent:yes

If mapping a network drive on a windows server, ensure to setup SMB1.0/CIFS File Sharing Support and the WebDav Redirect features.